# How to bind a 3D model to specific points on a face, using ARcore's Augmented Faces

Tags: augmented-reality, arcore

as you can guess from my question, im a newbie to ARCore. I've been testing out the augmented faces API, which works fine. Now I want to add my own 3D model, which I've developed using Blender. When I import it in, the 3D model floats, rather than sticking to a certain area on the face. My question is how does one do this?  I know about the canonical face mesh file that you can have for your reference, but how does one do it?

Do I just scale my 3d model according to it in blender?
Or is there some way I should bind it to the certain pre-identified anchors.

Thanks in advance for your help!

PS, the 3D model is a sunglasses. It would help me a ton if someone could guide me step by step how to align it so that I can import it on my face. Please help a newbie out, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

To be able to do so, you can do the following:
1. You should download [canonical_face_mesh.fbx](https://github.com/google-ar/sceneform-android-sdk/tree/master/assets) from sdk
2. Open this model model and import your sunglasses and adjust according to the face
3. Export your model

You can also check out [this tutorial](https://medium.com/@harivigneshjayapalan/arcore-cupcakes-5-augmented-faces-api-2ca78681228e)

Comment: Any lead for ARCore iOS? Models are not rendering in ARCore but it's working fine in ARKit